# Url working in Google chrome inaccessible by Java w/Jsoup?

Tags: java, google-chrome, exception, networking, jsoup

I'm having quite a confusing problem. I have literally only been doing networking for a day, so please forgive me and I apologize if I am making a dumb error. My issue is that I cannot access a URL in a programmatic fashion which I can access through copy-pasting into chrome.

I am using a library called jsoup (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) which parses text out of raw html from a website. My goal in general is to use a base url to which I can attach a string, and get a webpage from it. I am using the code (edit for those who asked for more code, I know this is still sparse but this is the only code preceding the error)

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+of+";
url += search; //search is the passed in string
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //url is the String in question
```

to get the webpage. My ultimate goal is to use this method to get the text of the box at the top of chrome searches when you search for the definition of a word. I.e the box at the top here: https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+of+apple

However, I come to an issue when I attempt to use the above link as my url, for I get a org.jsoup.HttpStatusException, so I think it is a networking problem. What causes this url to work when typed into chrome, but not in Java? (I would also not be adverse to different ways to get the information in that box, since my current method feels a bit roundabout)

The full error message (edited in)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+of+apple
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
at test.Test.parseDef(Test.java:68)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:112)
```

To whomever answers, thank you for spending your time to help a networking newbie!

Comment: What's the exception message? In particular, what kind of HTTP error is Google giving you?

Comment: They probably want a `User-Agent`.

Comment: Can you provide more code. Its hard to identify based on single line of code.

Comment: Hi @Thatsillogical , I am having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, Google is accurately identifying your program as a "robot" and acting accordingly.  Google encourages robots to use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) and discourages them from using the human-oriented search interface.

In fact, all web spiders are supposed to check robots.txt, right?  Here is Google's: http://www.google.com/robots.txt.  Note that /search is disallowed.

Please see this question for further information.  It's basically the python version of your question.  [Why does Google Search return HTTP Error 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600536/why-does-google-search-return-http-error-403)

Comment: Okay, I understand what is behind my error now, but I've been using the Google search API in different parts of my program and the reason why I wasn't using it is because I wasn't able to get the concise box at the top of the search, only the actual search results. Is there a way to do this which I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jsoup you have to replace spaces with %20 and not with +.

Try this url :
https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20apple

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20";
url += search; //search is the passed in string
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it causes the exact same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link)
        .data("query", "Java")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .cookie("auth", "token")
        .timeout(1000)
        .post();
}
```

Comment: //replace link with url you want;
//to use this you have download jsoup-latest-version.jar and include in library
//doc will contain the response of that request.