# why my code is returning 403 forbidden acess

Tags: java, http, http-status-code-403

I am trying to make a http get request using java ,when i am executing the code ,i am getting `403 forbidden`code .Is there any way to get rid of that ?my code is

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.*;


public class Http {
private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
public static void main(String [] args){

    Http http=new Http();
    try {
        http.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void get() throws Exception{
    URL ob=new URL("http://www.google.com/search?q=vamsi");
    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) ob.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("USER_AGENT", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code is "+responseCode);
    BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String input;
    StringBuffer response =new StringBuffer();
    while((input=buf.readLine())!=null){
        response.append(input);

    }
    buf.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}   


}
```

Comment: Can we assume you can successfully visit that URL from (a) a browser and (b) the command line using `curl` or `wget` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Search will deny your request if you are doing it outside of their API and Terms of Service.

```
$ wget http://www.google.com/search?q=vamsi
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 74.125.225.212, 74.125.225.210, 74.125.225.211, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|74.125.225.212|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-02-01 23:21:08 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

They may be looking at your `User-Agent` header. If you add one that resembles a browser, it *may* work, though you are circumventing the Terms of Service and seeking unsupported behavior. (Sorry, I too tried this once.)

See also [Why does Google Search return HTTP Error 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600536/why-does-google-search-return-http-error-403)

FYI, this is a common restriction of major search engines (Google, Bing, Yahoo). There are some that you can query programatically; you will have to use those.

Comment: *"... though you're really entering undefined behavior"* - And violating their ToS!  **WARNING:** - Google would be within their rights to black-list your IP address for spoofing your User-Agent to side-step the ToS restriction.

Comment: I think you're right, I tried using a FF plugin called Poster and set the header: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36` and got 200OK response

Comment: @Paul: dude is there a way to spoof ?

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh - dude.  You do not want to do that.  Seriously!

Comment: @StephenC: I mean ,i just want to know a method,if i can do that ..just for knowledge sake !

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh, yes, though spoofing by definition enters undefined  or forbidden behavior, so the answer (if one were given) may not work two months from now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
```

Comment: You had "USER_AGENT" entered in your code, but instead should be "User-Agent"; That fixed the problem.