# 403 error urllib crawling sites like google

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to crawl sites like google for a project and I keep on getting 403 errors. some sites work and others don't. none of the sites that i'm using have a apis other than google so thats out  the window. any thoughts

```
FNLURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=test"

try:
    x = urllib.request.urlopen(FNLURL)
    req = urllib.request.Request(FNLURL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    print(respData)

except Exception as t:
    print(str(t))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600536/why-does-google-search-return-http-error-403

Comment: I dont have a API to use on things other than google

Comment: In this case I suggest you to rotate proxies for each request you make

Comment: Doesn't seem to work